# rotating camera three.js

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js

I am trying when somebody click on button to move camera around object. But I dont want to move object(it need to be centered).

I am having:

and js functions

```
function MoveUp()
{
    camera.position.y -=50;
}
function MoveDown()
{
    camera.position.y +=50;
}
```

but this is moving object down/up when i click on button.
is there any posibility just to move camera arround and how?
My objects are only cubes..
example:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'drvo.jpg' ) } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'drvo.jpg' ) } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'drvo.jpg' ) } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'beton.jpg' ) } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'beton.jpg' ) } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'beton.jpg' ) } )
    ] );

    cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.position.z = 450;
    scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: as a side note, you can just create 2 MeshBasicMaterial's and pass them in multiple times to save on resources.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the camera position, while keeping it's orientation. I guess you want to reorientate the camera so that it will point to your cube (in effect, centering it). After you move the camera, try `camera.lookAt(cube.position);` This needs to be the last thing in your MoveUp and MoveDown

Comment: It is working a little bether, but it is not natural rotation :

function MoveUp()
{
 camera.position.y +=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}
function MoveDown()
{
 camera.position.y -=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}
function MoveLeft()
{
 camera.position.x -=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}

function MoveRight()
{
 camera.position.x +=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}
function ZoomOut()
{
 camera.position.z +=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}
function ZoomIn()
{
 camera.position.z -=50;
 camera.lookAt(cube.position);
}

but still sometimes on one action it do something else

Comment: what's wrong with that? do you want the motion to be a smooth animation rather than just snapping into place?

Comment: Its not very clear how it should be working and how it is working. A jsFiddle or screenshots would help. You can always use TrackBallControls or RollControls instead of rolling your own. If the camera appears tilted sideways after lookAt(), you can try setting the camera.up property (plenty of related questions on SO). Setting only one axis will not give natural orbit, as the camera distance will slightly change - to fix that you need some more math to move the camera around an imaginary sphere around the object. For examples look at the code of the various built-in example Controls.

Comment: No, for example, when i click on MoveRight it goes right and zoom out for example...
Why is he zooming out? After manu clicks it stop rotating and it zoom out to much.
I can't rotate for 360 degree for example, around cube....

Comment: Thats because when you only change one axis in the move function. The camera will move straight along that axis in your "world", then turn to point your object. Naturally it will be farther from the object then. To fix that, you "need some more math to move the camera around an imaginary sphere around the object", so the camera distance from that object won't change. Again, look up the Controls examples, or use the built-in controls as they already handle those things, or search SO for already answered related questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am looking now at Controls examples, i will try to implement it....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the RollControls.js at three.js/examples/js/controls/RollControls.js and also at the examples two directories up. Since the controls are there, why try to do it yourself.